# Linux kernel Asymmetric key parser

Tags: linux, security, cryptography, kernel, x509

I'm trying to figure out how Linux kernel asymmetric key management works. My question is: is the x509 parser the only available key parser in the linux kernel? If, for example, I have my key stored in PEM format, how can I add this key to kernel keyring?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PEM is more or less a wrapper format. It uses header and footers to indicate start and end of base 64 x509 (DER) encoded certificates. So if you can add an X509 certificate it should be very easy to add one that is "PEM encoded". PEM is adding an ASCII armor, i.e. it can be interpreted as text.

You can use `openssl` command line to convert a certificate from PEM to DER and vice versa:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.pem -outform DER -out certificate.der
```

You can then store the certificate in the kernel, which seems to treat the key as a BLOB of data.

---

It seems you can store the key in any binary format. So if you don't want to use certificates then you could encode your public key in some standard format. For public keys that is usually `SubjectPublicKey` which is the public key part *within* an X5.09 certificate.

To convert just the public key (from a public or private key) use:

```
openssl rsa -in private.pem -pubout -outform DER -out public.der
```

---

If you want to store the absolute minimum, easy to handle key then you could just store the modulus as big endian unsigned integer (of exactly the key size), and set the public exponent statically to the value `010001` (in hex). This is mostly useful if you don't have the DER encoding routines available in your application.

---

Make sure that your key is stored as "permanent" key in the kernel though otherwise it will still expire.

Comment: Actually my problem is that I don't want to deal with certificates at all (if it would be possible). I simply want to add my public key (in whatever format it is) to the kernel keyring. The problem with certificates is that they include an expiration date and since I'm working on an embedded system I don't have the guarantee that my system date is correct (indeed, I'm quite sure it is not). This would certainly cause an error when the system checks the certificate validity.

Comment: Expanded answer. Useful link: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-key-retention/